# How to sort rows in alphabetical order with selections at top, when initial selections are set during onFirstDataRendered/onRowDataUpdated?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, gridview-sorting

In my grouped Ag-grid (React), I am initializing the selections using rowNode.setSelected during onFirstDataRendered and onRowDataUpdated.

To sort the grid alphabetically with selections at the top, I cannot use sort/comparator fields in columnDefs like below, because my selections are initialized during onFirstDataRendered and onRowDataUpdated, so no node is selected at the time when columnDefs comparator function will run.

```
        export const ColDef = [
        {
            headerName: 'col1',
            enableRowGroup: true,
            field: 'name',
            rowGroupIndex: 2,
            hide: true,
            comparator: sortComparator,
            sort: 'asc',
        },
        ... ];

const sortComparator = (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isDescending) => {      
    if ((nodeA.isSelected() || nodeA.isSelected() == undefined) && !nodeB.isSelected()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!nodeA.isSelected() && (nodeB.isSelected() || nodeB.isSelected() == undefined)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return valueA == valueB ? 0 : valueA > valueB ? 1 : -1;
};
```

What else I can do?